# What is the proper way to pass traffic using GRE tunnel (or any vNIC) using eBPF?

Tags: networking, tunnel, ebpf

I have a [GRE link](https://david-waiting.medium.com/a-beginners-guide-to-generic-routing-encapsulation-fb2b4fb63abb) set up on a VM using the following commands: `ip tunnel add tap0 mode gre local <foo> remote <bar>` and the counterpart on a different VM (in the same subnet) is exactly the same except `foo<->bar`

I have created and an eBPF `tc` program that calls `bpf_clone_redirect` to copy packets to the tunnel device on one of the hosts (i.e duplicating the traffic to `tap0` link):

```
SEC("tc")

SEC("tc")
int tc_ingress(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    __u32 key = 0;
    struct destination *dest = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&destinations, &key);

    if (dest != NULL) {
        struct bpf_tunnel_key key = {};
        int ret;

        key.remote_ipv4 = dest->destination_ip;
        key.tunnel_id = dest->iface_idx;
        key.tunnel_tos = 0;
        key.tunnel_ttl = 64;
        ret = bpf_skb_set_tunnel_key(skb, &key, sizeof(key), 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            // error setting the tunnel key, do not redirect simply continue.
            return TC_ACT_OK;
        }
        // zero flag means that the socket buffer is 
        // cloned to the iface egress path.
        bpf_clone_redirect(skb, dest->iface_idx, 0);
    }
    return TC_ACT_OK;
}
}
```

I see the traffic passed to the GRE link `tap0` by running `tcpdump -i tap0` but I dont see the traffic on its remote counterpart...

1. Is it necessary in such scenario to define an address for the device (ala `ip addr <> dev tap0`)?
2. What is the proper way of defining such tunnels?
3. If I have `iptable` rules set up on `eth0` would it block traffic sent to the GRE link? If "yes" is there a way to bypass those?

Comment: Do you see the packets on the native device (the device on which the GRE tunnel is created)? If yes, are the packets encapsulated? If not, did you try tracing where the packets are dropped with cilium/pwru?

Comment: @pchaigno
1. Nope I dont see the packets on `eth0` - To be clear if I am duplicating packets *from* `eth0` to `tap0`, in that case, I should see *both* packets (original and dup) on `eth0` (assuming its the underlying device) ? 
2. How can I use cilium/pwru to trace where they are dropped?

Comment: You should be able to trace the packet with the various filters. See https://github.com/cilium/pwru#usage. A `kfree_skb` function should be shown if packets are dropped. I suspect you just need to set the tunnel ID, TTL, and outer destination IP via `bpf_skb_set_tunnel_key`.

Comment: @pchaigno is the tunnel id the interface id of `tap0` (the GRE tunnel) ?

Comment: For VXLAN, tunnels it's the Virtual Network Identifier (VNI). For GRE, I'm not sure. It may be unused or it could be the optional Key. I think the outer destination IP is what matters most here.

Comment: @pchaigno So now I am seeing the packets going out of eth0 via `sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -Q out`, for example: `IP 10.0.100.5 > 10.0.100.8: GREv0, length 56: IP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX > 10.0.100.5.24497: Flags [.], ack 22842250, win 1687, options [nop,nop,TS val 904755902 ecr 2911175870], length 0`. But for some reason I'm not seeing it on the paired machine (10.0.100.8), not even on `eth0` for that machine.. Thoughts?

Comment: If you see them on the native interface of one machine but not of the other, then the packets must be dropped in between. Any firewall rules in between? I understand those are two VMs on the same machine, right? How are they connected?

Comment: @pchaigno not sure if their on the same machine, these are (Azure) cloud VM's on the same subnet. Also I've seen a discussion on cillium's eBPF slack channel with somewhat similar issue (Except traffic was redirected to a veth and not a GRE tunnel) where the writer stated: "Solved:
Missing TCA_BPF_FLAG_ACT_DIRECT in the netlink command.". Would you know where and how this flag is used? should I use it as well somewhere?

Comment: @pchaigno I have now found that GRE isn't supported on Azure VNETs :( .. This explains this behavior (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/496591/does-azure-virtual-network-support-gre.html)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to route to a GRE tunnel please use the `bpf_skb_set_tunnel_key` struct provided. See examples in https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/5bfc75d92efd494db37f5c4c173d3639d4772966/samples/bpf/tc_l2_redirect_kern.c).

Per my use case -

For anyone trying to create a GRE tunnel on **Azure VM**'s please note that this is, currently, **not possible** per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/496591/does-azure-virtual-network-support-gre.html

Comment: Note this doesn't answer the question you posted, which made no mention of Azure. It might be best to keep the original question, mention `bpf_skb_set_tunnel_key` as the solution, and optionally open another question for the Azure aspect.